# Get link to Facebook profile with passport.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

I am using `passport.js` to let users log in.

I am wondering if it's possible to create a link to their profile on their social media account?

For instance, when logging in using Facebook, I can get an ID, but the link `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=__ID__` doesn't work.

Maybe it's not possible at all since some Facebook users might have their Facebook profile hidden even though they use their account as login for other websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i know, this is not possible using passport at least.

The reason why the link doesn't work is that the ID returned by Facebook is always app specific so different apps would get different IDs for the same user. So you don't get the "official" ID of a user which you could use for building the URL.

However, the Facebook API returns a link to a users timeline which should be the one you are looking for (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/). But from what i see in the documentation of passport, this information is not returned. So if you want to get the link you need to work with the Facebook API directly.